# Assign base class instance to a derived instance in c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to initialize an instance of derived class with an instance of base class. I'm doing so because I'm obliged to use an already existing data in base class to initialize my derived class. I can't use constructor to initialize these fields in derived class  I would like to have something like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

class Base {
protected:
    int i;

public:
    //Base(const Base&) {/*...*/}

    Base(int &in):i(in){}

    Base& operator=(const Base &src) {
        i = (src.i);
        return *this;
    }

    void display(){ cout<<i<<endl;/*display the content of i*/ }
};

class Derived: public Base {
protected:
    int j;

public:
    //Derived(const Base& b) : Base(b) {}

    using Base::operator=;

    Derived& operator=(const Derived &src) {
        *this = static_cast<const Base&>(src);
        j = (src.j);
        return *this;
    }

    // additional method trying to modify b::j and preferably b::i ?
    void setJ(int& f){i=f;}
};

int main() {
    int a =1;
    int b=2;

    Base* base = new Base(a);
    Derived* derived;

    *derived=*base; // this should initialize derived::i with base::i in the     best case and make a copy in derived::j if there is no possible         access to modify derived.i//
    derived->setJ(b);
    derived->display();

    return 0;
}
```

output : segmentation fault (core dumped)

requirement: can't initialize derived class using constructor on `i` or `j` field because I don't have getters/setters on field `Base.i` in base class !

Comment: What's this `*this = static_cast<const Base&>(src);` contortionism about?

Comment: *"I can't use constructor to initialize these fields in derived class"* Why not?

Comment: To call your assignment operator use `*derived=*base; `.

Comment: I corrected the posted code, actually I used *derived=*base. But I get SegFault when displaying the content

Comment: @ChristianHackl can't because I want to inisilize derived::i from an exsiting base::i which is protected and i have no getter in the base class for i ! these are constraints under which I develop

Comment: @decltype_auto tried this *this = static_cast<const Base&>(src); for initializing/ copying from existing instance of base class

Comment: `protected` is exactly meant for descendants who must access their parents' internals.

Comment: @decltype_auto objective is to initialize an instance of [Derived] with an existing instance of [Base]. [Derived] only add extra methods for manipulating same attributes of base !

Comment: that is both obvious and doesn't invalidate any remarks made, so what's your point please?

Comment: @decltype_auto
Well I tried the compiler said can't access to Base.i because it's protected.
What I want, is just to initialize a derived class instance from an existing base class instance, which will allow me to copy all the data in base class instance inside the derived class instance.  I have no getters/setters on the data in the base class ...

Comment: [live counter-example on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb5843d16b266557)

Comment: Have you considered properly formatting & indenting your code?

Comment: `Derived* derived; *derived = *base` ..... eh you are assigning to something that does not exist.

Comment: Woh! You have quite a lot of issues here. To begin with, your derived is unconstructable!

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to initialize an instance of derived class with an instance
>   of base class.

```
Base::Base(const Base&) {/*...*/}

Derived::Derived(const Base& b) : Base(b) {}
```

Comment: getting error 
 extra qualification ‘base::’ on member ‘base’ [-fpermissive]|

Comment: it's not `base::` but `Base::`

Comment: error: extra qualification ‘Base::’ on member ‘Base’ [-fpermissive]|

Comment: That are implementations, not declarations. If you use them inside the class definition, you must remove the scope resolution.

Answer (score 0):

To be more specific, use the constructor of derived to build a derived from a base:

```
#include<iostream>

class Base {
protected:
    int i;

public:
    Base(int &in) : i(in) {}

    void display() {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived: public Base {
public:

    Derived(const Base &b) : Base(b) {}

    void setJ(int &f){ i = f; }
};

int main() {
    int a = 1, b = 2;

    Base base(a);
    Derived derived(base);

    derived.setJ(b);
    derived.display();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this works as I wanted, thanks. But one should bare in mind this use the default copy constructor, if there is specific treatments, one should define proper one !